# CloudCompare fails to launch with error: "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0"

Tags: linux, qt

In the last week, CloudCompare has suddenly stopped launching. When trying to launch via desktop icon, nothing happens. When trying to launch via commandline (e.g. `$ cloudcompare.CloudCompare`) nothing happens and I get the following error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Trying to launch CloudCompare with `sudo`/as root user returns a slightly different error message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

Having looked around Github, here and various other forums, this seems to be a problem that people have encountered with other programs that use Qt and/or OpenGL (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478208/qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display-when-trying-to-debug-linux-app-wit), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979185/qt-5-1-qapplication-without-display-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-displ), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924997/pyqt5-could-not-connect-to-display)). I also realise that this isn't really enough information to debug the problem, so if there is any other diagnostic info I can/should provide, let me know and I will add it.

**EDIT:** I can actually get CloudCompare working again by completely uninstalling it and then re-installing it. However that doesn't explain the original problem or how to solve it.

### My Environment

- **OS & Version:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- **CC Version:** v2.8.1 (latest)
- **Graphics card:** Intel Haswell Mobile
- **Qt version:** 5.2.1

Comment: execute xhost + on terminal and after execute cloudcompare without sudo

Comment: Do you mean: `$ xhost +` and then `$ cloudcompare.CloudCompare`?

Because just tried that and it didn't work unfortunately. Still get the same error message.

Comment: [Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402180/cloudcompare-fails-to-launch-with-error-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-d/436337#436337) is on the sister site.

Answer (score -2):

I resolve this by installing `qt5-default` on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```